# When I release an android app in another country for a beta test, do the comments and reviews of the app follow to my app store?

Tags: android, mobile, release-management, android-developer-api, beta-testing

Title pretty much says it all. I was hoping to release an android app in a low-risk environment where I could beta test in one country and then release in my home country. Do the ratings and reviews of the app transfer from one Google play store to another?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)